# Sending arduino data to mysql database using phpadmin and xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, arduino-uno, esp8266

I want to send my arduino sensor data to mysql databse using XAMPP and PHPmyadmin. I have been using esp8266 for the wifi connection. But i am unable to send the value. And in actually i have to send four values but for the time being i am sending only one value. So also please tell how to send multiple values. I have written the php file and save in to htdocs of apache. and i am using it on windows 10.

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspClient.h>
#include <WiFiEspUdp.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <SPI.h>

IPAddress ip(192,168,8,1);
char ssid[] = "ZONG MBB-E8372-B67D";           // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "08522547";           // your network password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;   // the Wifi radio's status
 int photocellPin = 4;  // Analog input pin on Arduino we connected the SIG      pin from sensor
int photocellReading;  // Here we will place our reading

char server[] =  "192.168.8.1";
// Initialize the Ethernet client object
   WiFiEspClient espclient;

 SoftwareSerial soft(2,3); // RX, TX
void setup() {
// initialize serial for debugging
Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
soft.begin(115200);
// initialize ESP module
 WiFi.init(&soft);

// check for the presence of the shield
 if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
// don't continue
while (true);
}

 // attempt to connect to WiFi network
 while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
 Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
 // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
 status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

      // you're connected now, so print out the data
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  }

  void loop() {

     photocellReading = analogRead(photocellPin); // Fill the sensorReading with the information from sensor

  // Connect to the server (your computer or web page)  
    if (espclient.connect(server, 80)) {
  espclient.println("GET /write_data7.php?"); // This
    espclient.println("value="); // This

  espclient.println(photocellReading); // And this is what we did in the     testing section above. We are making a GET request just like we would from our browser but now with live data from the sensor
    espclient.println(" HTTP/1.1"); // Part of the GET request
  espclient.println("Host: 192.168.8.1"); // IMPORTANT: If you are using         XAMPP you will have to find out the IP address of your computer and put it here (it is explained in previous article). If you have a web page, enter its address (ie.Host: "www.yourwebpage.com")
  espclient.println("Connection: close"); // Part of the GET request    telling the server that we are over transmitting the message
 espclient.println(); // Empty line
 espclient.println(); // Empty line
  espclient.stop();    // Closing connection to server

 }

   else {
   //   If Arduino can't connect to the server (your computer or web page)
 Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
  }

    // Give the server some time to recieve the data and store it. I used 10 seconds here. Be advised when delaying. If u use a short delay, the server might not capture data because of Arduino transmitting new data too soon.
   delay(10000);
    }
```

following is the php code:

```
<?php
//connecting to the database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'connected_car_1');
define('DB_USER','Maryam1');
define('DB_PASSWORD','telecom1213');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

 $sql = "INSERT INTO connected_car_1.sensor (value) VALUES ('".$_GET["value"]."')";    

   // Execute SQL statement

  mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and this is my serial monitor output: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNCth.png)

I am very new to coding in arduino as well as php and databases. So kindly help me where i am doing wrong. And do i have to provide the ip address of phpmyadmin ie. 127.0.0.1. if yes. then where? And do i have to use commands like cipstart cipsend in my code..if yes..then how?

Comment: Your client is not  connecting to your server.  Is your server working?  Did you browse to it with a web browser and verify that the 'value' is going into the database?

Comment: if i use the url: http://localhost/write_data7.php?value=100 , i do get 100 in my database. but its not working with arduino

Comment: To make sure the server is available through your local computer's firewall, try to do it it from another computer.

Comment: server means my own computer? right?

Comment: Yes the (web) server would be the application running on your computer at port 80.  If your firewall is blocking it, the esp would never be able to connect to it.

Comment: how can i see that application? sorry for asking stupid questions..but i am really new so i dont know much

Comment: browse from computer 2 to http://computer1/write_data7.php?value=101